# Select column by percentage of non zero values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big sparse dataframe and I'd like to remove automatically the columns (the column keys/names are dynamic, so in principle I don't know the column number and the naming) with a number of non zero element below a certain percentage of the total row number.

Thank you!

Comment: A sample data would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has a [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) function, which has a `thresh` parameter. Simply set that to the number of non-zero values you need to keep. So

```
df.dropna(thres=int(len(df)*0.8), axis=1)
```

Will drop columns where less than 80% of the rows are complete.

Comment: Thank you, this works only if I convert the zeros to Nan 
df.replace(to_replace=0, value=np.nan) and then df.dropna(thres=int(len(df)*0.8), axis=1)

Answer (score 1):

@user3620915
it's thresh instead of thres

```
df.replace(to_replace=0, value=np.nan)
df.dropna(thresh=int(len(df)*0.8), axis=1)
```

DataFrame.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)